# How to set Google Maps API key in PrimeFaces extensions gChart

Tags: google-maps, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I'm using PrimeFaces extensions (6.1.0) to create some charts using `pe:gChart`.

One of the charts is a [geo chart as appears in the showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/gchart/geochart.jsf). No problems so far.

Another chart I need to render is a [marker geo chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#marker-geocharts). This is not explained in the PrimeFaces extensions showcase, but I was hoping this would be an easy job. I ended up with this model (which I believe is correct):

```
GChartModelBuilder builder = new GChartModelBuilder();
builder.setChartType(GChartType.GEO);
builder.addOption("displayMode", "markers");
builder.addOption("region", country);
builder.addColumns("City", "Total");
for (...) {
  builder.addRow(city, total);
}
```

When I run my project I do see a map for this chart. The region is correct, but no markers appear. There is marker data generated though.

My browser console tells me:

> Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error

Is there any way I can set this API key without creating hacks?

### Update

I've created a custom renderer:

```
public class MyGChartsRenderer extends GChartRenderer
{

  @Override
  protected void encodeMarkup(FacesContext context, GChart chart) throws IOException
  {
    ...

    this.startScript(writer, chart.getClientId());
    // Appended ?key=xxxxx to the URL (other lines are not modified)
    writer.writeAttribute("src", "https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=xxxxx", null);
    this.endScript(writer);
  }

}
```

And loaded it in the `faces-config.xml`:

```
<render-kit>
  <renderer>
    <component-family>org.primefaces.extensions.component</component-family>
    <renderer-type>org.primefaces.extensions.component.GChartRenderer</renderer-type>
    <renderer-class>MyGChartsRenderer</renderer-class>
  </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

But the Google Maps API error keeps appearing in my console.

Comment: Added issue to PFE: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/473

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER: I created an answer, not because it is *the* answer but because it is so much information that it won't fit in a comment in any way any way (hmmm ;-))**

DISCLAIMER 2: I might have missed some things and did not actually try... Hope you don't mind.

Note: Three months ago PrimeFaces extensions updated to a newer Google charts api [version according to the commits](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/commit/67caec71ae63d59187c7f003f15d6f6be47ec476) and [issue 452](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/452) with upcoming changes so I focussed on that!

In the [PrimeFaces-extensions gchart.js](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces-extensions/gchart/gchart.js) I noticed

```
google.charts.load('current', {
        packages : [ 'corechart', 'geochart', 'orgchart' ]
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
            that.draw();
        });
});
```

While on on [Visualization: GeoChart  |  Charts  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#overview) I saw

```
google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages':['geochart'],
    // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
    // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
    'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);
```

Related tot the issue commit/fix/issue, in the PrimeFaces extensions showcase source **trunk** I also noted they explicitly load

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

in the xhtml.

Lots of upcoming changes, so the most future proof solution would be to try 6.2-SNAPSHOT and create a real good fix where you

- add a mapsApiKey property and getters/setters to [GChart.java](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/extensions/component/gchart/GChart.java)
- add .attr("mapsApiKey", chart.getMapsApiKey()) to [GChartRenderer.java](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/extensions/component/gchart/GChartRenderer.java)
- add `this.mapsApiKey = cfg.mapsApiKey` -and `'mapsApiKey': this.mapsApiKey` to [gchart.js](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces-extensions/gchart/gchart.js) in the right places

Comment: After further reading I found out that indeed some changes in JavaScript are required. Let's see if I can find some time to fix it and possibly offer a PR on GitHub. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45479491/880619) for now.

Comment: Jasper I am the main developer of PF Extensions now.  Can you comment in this ticket on exactly what needs to be fixed so I can fix it?  https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/473

Comment: I've read the Git issue. Seems clear now, right? By the way, I've tried to create a resource handler to patch the JS, but I couldn't find where `gchart.js` was loaded.

Comment: build time, all the .js files are aggregated and minified into primefaces-extensions.js and that is referenced as a `@ResourceDependency` in GChart.java

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround / hack I've put this script in my XHTML:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxx&amp;v=3&amp;callback=google.loader.callbacks.maps&amp;sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: I plan on adding this functionality to the PF Extensions 6.2 release.